# What is the work done by a force that changes with time $F(t)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

There is a force that changes with time. (F(t))

And the position vector is also given as a function time. (r(t))

Here how do we find the work done by F(t) between, lets's say t=0 and t=1?

This is my actual time-dependent force:

[image: F(t)]

And this is the position vector:

[image: r(t)]

sometimes I get confused because of those *i* and *j* s...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work done during a short interval of time, $[t, t+\Delta t]$ is given by usual formula
$$
\Delta W = \mathbf{F}(t)\cdot \Delta \mathbf{r}(t),
$$
where $\mathbf{F}(t)$ and $\Delta \mathbf{r}(t)$ are the force and the displacement at the beginning of the interval. The total work is then approximately a sum over all the intervals, and this approximation becomes exact as the length of the interval goes to zero:
$$
W = \sum_{all intervals} \mathbf{F}(t)\cdot \Delta \mathbf{r}(t)
=
\int_{\mathbf{r}(0)}^{\mathbf{r}(1)} \mathbf{F}(t)\cdot d \mathbf{r}(t)
=
\int_{0}^{1} \mathbf{F}(t)\cdot \dot{\mathbf{r}}(t)dt
=
\int_{0}^{1} \mathbf{F}(t)\cdot \mathbf{v}(t)dt
=
\int_{0}^{1} P(t)dt,
$$
where
$$
P(t) = \mathbf{F}(t)\cdot \mathbf{v}(t)
$$
is the instantaneous power of the force.

Comment: Quick comment: $0,1$ are maybe not the best labels for the initial and final times - maybe $t_1,t_2$?

Comment: $[0,1]$ is the time interval specified in the question. $t_1,t_2$ would certainly make the exposition more general... but it could be more confusing for the author of the question (I am not even sure that they are comfortable with the passage to the integral).

Comment: I know why we have to take the integral of it. but I still couldn't solve my problem :/ thanks anyway

Comment: @Greyfia I am not sure what could still pose the difficulty: you know the force vector (note the typo - $i$ is missing in the first term), you know the position vector, you can differentiate it to get the velocity, substitute to the formula in my answer and integrate.